# Alternative to GCM for Android Devices for Push Notifications?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

Currently, in order to push notifications to an android app on the android operating system, it appears the app needs to integrate Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) APIs. The App Server currently pushes data through GCM and GCM will push data to specific devices.

This is a silly question, but I was wondering if it is possible to replace GCM in this process? In other words, is it possible to have an alternative server as opposed to GCM? The motive is to hide the data from the GCM server.

**Before:**
App Server ==> GCM ==> Android App

**New:**
App Server ==> Custom Cloud Messaging ==> Android App

Comment: You are certainly welcome to integrate your own sort of "long-polling" mechanism, like MQTT. If the concern is to "hide the data from the GCM server", you might consider just encrypting it.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare . As you suggested, if I decide to integrate own sort of long-polling mechanism, will all this logic happen inside the android app in the form of a Service that polls the App Server for notifications? I assume the Service route will allow the app to run some code even when the app is not running. Just concerned if this is going to drain battery life...

Comment: "will all this logic happen inside the android app in the form of a Service that polls the App Server for notifications?" -- yes, or a service in a separate process. "Just concerned if this is going to drain battery life" -- in general, it will. Getting this stuff to work with minimal battery drain is supposed to be fairly tricky, as you're relying upon incoming packets on mobile data connections to wake up the device out of sleep mode and stuff. Others have done it, so it's clearly doable.

Comment: Thanks, good to know it is possible going the Service route, even if it is tricky to maintain minimal battery drain.  I assume going the GCM route is the most efficient in terms of battery drain. Since the goal is to hide data, I think Encrypting the payload is the best option as you suggested

Comment: For a ready-made commercial implementation of a standalone MQTT push notification service, check out Pushy (https://pushy.me/), which can be self-hosted for data security and privacy requirements. Full disclosure - I founded Pushy.

Answer (score 4):

You can ***use app-directed*** ***sms***/ port-directed sms.

Send sms from the server(SMS gateway) to a particular port on which your app will be listening.This sms will act as GCM message.

Using this approach you don't have to worry about long running service draining the battery. Also sms  are almost real time and doesn't require internet connection.

However there are some phones don't support port directed sms.

For port directed sms you need to register a broadcast receiver something like below:

```
<receiver
android:name = ".SmsReceiver">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.DATA_SMS_RECEIVED" />
    <data 
        android:scheme="sms"
        android:host="*"
        android:port="8095" />
    </intent-filter>
```

The port directed sms does not appear in user's sms inbox if properly supported by phone.

Comment: Thanks @rupesh jain. Interesting solution! Does this mean that the App Server will basically send an SMS Text Message to the device based on Phone Number? Does this assume the device has a Phone Line (ex: Verizon)? Will the message appear as a text message on the phone? With this approach, I assume the app needs to create a Service that listens to SMS Port and is then able to handle the payload.

Comment: While the SMS path has some potential, it's actually a pretty old school way to do it.  First thing is that the costs of SMS adds up REALLY quickly.  I did this before in my previous company and we racked up literally $10K/month of SMS bills.  Secondly, you need to verify the phone numbers are accurate and how they route.  Each carrier handles things differently - whether it's binary SMS - there are some limitations on GSM vs. CDMA.  Honestly, a huge number of headaches.

Answer (score 3):

Replacing GCM is actually not a trivial task.  I would have to strongly advise against doing a long-polling mechanism as suggested earlier - the truth is that going down that path would be extremely expensive in terms of resources (battery life) and managing it would be a nightmare. There are going to be tons of error conditions that you're gonna need to address - from network drops to managing guaranteed delivery.

Full Disclosure:  I work for Magnet Systems which has a product - Magnet Message - that provides these capabilities and more.

What we did was create a persistent socket to the server.  (BTW, this is what GCM does as well as Apple's APNS).  This socket is used to be able to "push" messages to the device.  By understanding the connectivity on the socket, you'll understand the presence of devices and know if you can send messages to them.

Nevertheless, it's still a challenge to address things like pushing to an app that is offline or killed - and across platforms (probably don't want to forget the other 40% of iOS users) - so there are different challenges there.  To address this, we send a "signal" via GCM to notify that there is a pending message and have a Broadcast Receiver that can go to our server and fetch the messages securely.

Since we allow you to deploy our server code in your environment, we don't have to see anything that you send.  (Of course, we have a SaaS model as well).

At any rate, you can take a look at what we've done at http://developer.magnet.com.  It's free to play with and we've got a bunch of open source stuff.

Comment: I haven't tried but check Pushy. http://eladnava.com/pushy-a-new-alternative-to-google-cloud-messaging/

Comment: This is very dumb, but I can't actually try Magnet because the page won't scroll down. Regardless of how I try to scroll to try the download the trial apps, the page jumps back to the top. My Chrome browser window cannot get any larger than full HD, so I simply have no way of reaching that area of the page. I'm mystified how a front-end developer manages to mess up something as rudimentary as scrolling.

Answer (score 3):

It is not recommended to bypass GCM since any other mechanism you might use will require a persistent connection from the phone to your server which will be a battery hog. GCM already has one connection open all the time so it should be reused as much as possible.

It is however understandable that you want to hide data from the GCM servers. In that case it should be simply encrypted. The Chrome team (which uses GCM) has decided to do the same (hide payloads from the GCM server) and perhaps their solution for encryption would work for you as well. You can see what they did in 
https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!searchin/blink-dev/Intent$20to$20Ship$3A$20Push$20Messaging$20Payloads/blink-dev/Vga32co0YMQ/4i6qXvfeAwAJ

The same link contains a [demo](https://tests.peter.sh/push-generator/) and the [code](https://github.com/beverloo/peter.sh/tree/master/tests) for it.

Note that the purpose of those examples is to implement it in chrome which is not exactly what you want. However the actual encryption method could be reused for Android.